# How do you make a prediction (forecast) from a trained network for a given input in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am using the neural network toolbox that Matlab provides. I trained a NARX neural network for time series problems. I am trying to predict future values using the inputs I am giving to the neural network.

I am able to see the error graphs and the response for the testing and validation samples, but how do I test new samples? How can I make a prediction using the trained neural network? I could not find any documentation.

This was my attempt

```
>> net(input2')

ans = 

    [917.9814]
```

But no matter what the inputs are, I am getting the exact same output always....

Comment: I think you'll need to add the code you trained with and at least a description of your data

Comment: I haven't used any code yet... I used the GUI to create and train the network. Then I just saved the nn to the workspace and I am trying to use it with other data.

Comment: Did you insert your RAW input or did you run preprocessing (e.g. preparets)?